# Query the latest created index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, amazon-elasticsearch

I have a need to query the latest index that is created on Elasticsearch.

I have formed the below curl command

`curl -X GET "localhost/_cat/indices?h=i,creation.date.string"`

It is returning the response as follows:

```
accounting       2020-03-03T02:46:29.285Z
kibana_1         2020-03-02T00:58:14.386Z
```

Is there any way I can return this in a JSON format? I have been trying this and couldn't get a JSON response.

Comment: Try -H 'Content-Type: application/json' in curl command

Comment: This one return json format with date as Unix timestamp

curl -X GET "localhost/_all/_settings/index.creation_date"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible to return the response from the `_cat` API [in JSON](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#_response_as_text_json_smile_yaml_or_cbor). It is also possible to [sort the results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#sort) by `creation.date.string`.

Try this and the first element from the resulting array will be the last create index.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET "localhost/_cat/indices?h=i,creation.date.string&format=json&s=creation.date.string:desc"
```

Comment: Little modification if the prefix of the index is known. `curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices/index-prefix-*?h=i,creation.date.string&format=json&s=creation.date.string:desc&pretty"`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the format in query
/_cat/indices?format=json&h=i,creation.date.string